# How to create multiple websocket connections from client using socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am doing project where my requirement is to connect to muliple servers from clients and monitor multiple server resources like cpu,memory,etc..

Currently i am using socket.io library for multiple client to single server using websocket. Can anyone tell me how to create multiple socket based on ip address of server from client like tabbed putty (adding one more server)

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you create a new connection you have to pass a parameter to force a new connection: `var socket = io.connect(URL, {'force new connection': true });`

It is stated in their documentation http://socket.io/docs/client-api/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. but, If client add new server connection, how can i connect to this call. Can i write separate factory service methods for returning socket after connecting.. Can you please help me this?